# Stop iterating objects using __proto__

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets, stack-snippets-console

http://stacksnippets.net/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.js uses this function

```
function getProps(obj) {
    var props = [];

    do {
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (props.indexOf(prop) === -1) {
                props.push(prop);
            }
        }
    }
    while (obj = obj.__proto__);

    return props;
}
```

That is wrong because

- `__proto__` is not standard (is only defined in an annex for compatibility), and thus should be avoided. Moreover, not all objects inherit `__proto__`  from `Object.prototype`.
- `for...in` loops already iterate inherited properties.

See the redundancy:

```js
function getProps(obj) {
  var i = 0;
  do {
    var current = [];
    for (var prop in obj) current.push(prop);
    console.log('Iteration ' + ++i + ': ' + JSON.stringify(current.sort()));
  } while (obj = obj.__proto__);
}
var a = {};
a.a = 'a';
var b = Object.create(a);
b.b = 'b';
var c = Object.create(b);
c.c = 'c';
var d = Object.create(c);
d.d = 'd';
getProps(d);
```

Instead, the function should be

```
function getProps(obj) {
    var props = [];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        props.push(prop);
    }
    return props;
}
```

Or just use the ES5 [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function, as proposed in [The console should not display inherited properties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280201/195099).

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Note `Object.keys` only returns own properties. I think that would be better, but people could disagree.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I wonder if perhaps it was implemented this way to order the properties based on inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been done and will be out in the next deployment. Please ping me in a comment here if you find any problem with the solution.