# The console should not display inherited properties

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, stack-snippets-console

Currently, when you log an object to the virtual console, it shows all enumerable properties, both own and inherited.

I think the inherited ones should be filtered out. Otherwise, the result can be huge. The following example even freezes my browser for a second.

```js
console.log(document);
```

This could be achieved by replacing `getProps` with

```
function getProps(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj);
}
```